# Расстановка знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки следует поставит в следующих предложениях:
1. Когда Вам удобно (?) в понедельник или вторник? 
2. Когда Вам удобно (?) в понедельник? 
3. Скидка будет составлять 20% или 30% (?) зависит от выбранного товара

Comment: Вопрос выглядит как задание.

Comment: @Dmitry это не задание.

Comment: @Dmitry предложения из головы. Как пример.

Comment: what are your assumptions so far? What would you use?

Comment: Если первый вариант - закрытый список, не ожидающий ответа типа "нет, ни понедельник, ни вторник, давайте лучше в четверг", то корректнее будет спросить "когда вам удобнЕЕ", явно показывая что в вопросе сравниваются два варианта, а не запрашиваются общие соображения.

Comment: Я бы поставила тире в последнем.

Answer (score 3):

Мы имеем уточняющее обстоятельство времени (в двух первых примерах), которые отделяются запятой (по Розенталю).

> Когда вам удобно, в понедельник или во вторник? Когда вам удобно, в понедельник?
>
> Вам удобно в понедельник или во вторник? В понедельник или во вторник вам удобно?(Варианты).

Второе предложение не очень понятно. Допустим, что это говорит один человек.

> Скидка составит 20-30%, в зависимости от выбранного товара.(уточнение)

Можно разделить на два предложения, подчеркнуть разговорный характер.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. По поводу последнего предложения: я предполагал, что там тире нужно. "Скидка составит 20-30% - зависит от выбранного товара". Вместо тире можно поставить "что" : "скидка составит 20-30%, ЧТО зависит от выбранного товара. Не так ли?

Comment: Сама формулировка с "зависит" без союзов, плохо смотрится. Я бы сказала И зависит, это зависит, она зависит, но лучше "в зависимости"

Comment: Здесь я имел в виду "ЭТО (ЭТО обстоятельство) зависит..."

Comment: Такой вариант будет звучать неестественно. Во-первых здесь опускать "это" хотя и возможно - но не типично. Во вторых там не вполне корректно использовать настоящее время - ведь покупка еще не совершена, вы только прицениваетесь. Лучше использовать будущее время, тогда и "это" опустить будет проще (но в литературной речи лучше не опускать) Поэтому нормальный вариант построения фразы через сложное предложение будет примерно таким: `Скидка составит 20-30%, [и, но] [это] БУДЕТ ЗАВИСЕТЬ от выбранного товара`. Наиболее естественный вариант всё же - простое предложение через "в зависимости"

Comment: Все равно уточнение. Но авторские знаки никто не отменял, так что,  как говорится, welcome.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

1. Когда вам удобно? В понедельник или вторник?
2. Когда вам удобно? В понедельник?
3. It looks like a dialog. So:

   - Скидка будет составлять 20% или 30%?
   - Зависит от выбранного товара.

I'd better change the first sentence. Скидка будет 20% или 30%? You don't need to use the word составлять in this case.

Comment: Последнее предложение - не вопрос